# systemd list-units cuts service names

Tags: systemd

I want to get all service names which match a pattern.

This does not work:

```
systemctl list-units -t service --no-pager --no-legend| cut -d' ' -f1| grep mypattern
```

Long service names get cut.

Example:

```
fooo123@...abc-new.service
```

How can I list the whole unit name?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `--full` option:

> Do not ellipsize unit names and truncate unit descriptions in the output of list-units and list-jobs.

Here is the whole script:

```
systemctl list-units -t service --full| cut -d' ' -f1| grep mypattern | while read s; do systemctl status $s; done
```

Comment: I aliased that long ago... `alias systemctl='systemctl -l'`

Comment: @MichaelHampton a recursive alias. I was not aware that this works. Great :-)

Comment: Note that it might be important to also include a lot of other flags like `--no-legend` and `--plain` if you intend to use it in scripts. See [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/942128/549727). Also, ALWAYS test for your SPECIFIC version of systemd - some flags (in particular, `--quiet`) may not behave the same across different versions.