# Parsable output from systemctl (for example list all units)

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I am not happy with the output of systemctl

I have a script which parses the output of

```
systemctl list-units -t service --full --all
```

The beginning of the output look like this:

```
  UNIT                                   LOAD      ACTIVE     SUB          JOB   DESCRIPTION                                                                  
  after-local.service                    loaded    inactive   dead               /etc/init.d/after.local Compatibility                                        
● amavis.service                         not-found inactive   dead               amavis.service                                                               
  apparmor.service                       loaded    active     exited             Load AppArmor profiles                                                       
  auditd.service                         loaded    active     running            Security Auditing Service
```

On a different systemd the column with the dot (before amavis.service) does not exist.

Is there a machine/script readable output of systemctl?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use this for machine-parsable output, adding `--plain --no-legend`, for example:

```
systemctl list-units -t service --full --all --plain --no-legend
```

Comment: Sometimes, when there is a pending job for any unit in the list, it includes an additional column with the job status (eg.: "starting") which breaks parsing, because, for other units (that don't have any job), the value in that extra column is blank.

Answer (score 2):

you can get json (or `json-pretty`) output by setting the `--output` flag:

```
systemctl list-units \
  --type service \
  --full \
  --all \
  --output json \
  --no-pager
```

if your version of systemctl is without json output support, you can get json like so:

```
systemctl list-units \
  --type service \
  --full \
  --all \
  --plain \
  --no-legend \
  --no-pager \
  | sed 's/ \{1,\}/,/g' \
  | jq \
    --raw-input \
    --slurp \
    'split("\n") | map(split(",")) | .[0:-1] | map( { "unit": .[0], "load": .[1], "active": .[2], "sub": .[3] } )'
```